# Nix shell #! to refer to to shell.nix in a parent directory

Tags: nix, shebang, nix-shell

I start almost all my scripts lately with

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i bash
set -e
```

But this requires that the `default.nix`/`shell.nix` be in the same directory as the script which is not always the case. Is there a way to tell `nix-shell` to look at all parent directories for a `*.nix` file?

Comment: `-u` and `-o pipefail` are also good defaults. I use `set -euo pipefail`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items after `#! nix-shell` are basically regular `nix-shell` arguments, so you can add the file name like this.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i bash ../shell.nix
set -e
```

Path resolution happens relative to the script file.
When you use a directory path, it will look for `default.nix`, not `shell.nix` inside the directory.